# getting this error even after putting different keys in facial recognition door sample

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

even after entering the key I have been subscribed to a standard plan of the face api service but getting this error constantly.! Tried changing the end points and creating s0 tier API to but getting same error .

Comment: Er.. what error?

Comment: Invalid key ... And face recognition is exited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project is old, and does not allow for specifying the API endpoint.  I've made a fix in a [fork](https://github.com/cthrash/Facial-Recognition-Door) and a pull request to the main project.  Cognitive Service API keys are valid in only one region (i.e. you cannot use a westeurope key in westus, etc.)